# Why did all my questions get up-voted at once and then suddenly get down-voted?

Tags: support, reputation, voting

Someone suddenly up-voted all my questions since the beginning, then suddenly with 1 day ago my questions got down-voted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See https://apple.stackexchange.com/help/serial-voting-reversed (a link which is actually displayed in your reputation history in your profile).

Basically, an unknown user decided to upvote a lot of your posts, a behavior which the system detected and corrected by invalidating/reversing those upvotes. There is nothing you could have done to prevent that from happening.

Comment: I was so excited to get so many up-votes but then, Hmmm all up votes got corrected!

Comment: @Sayan I know the feeling, but the system is also designed to protect you as well (e.g. from someone who has a grudge and decides to downvote a whole heap of your posts). So, it's a balancing act and, while not perfect, it is better than any online system I've seen so far. :)